# How to write to txt file which options been selected?

Tags: python, tkinter

My current goal is to send data to a txt file of which out of the 3 radio buttons have been selected for each option.

here is my current code of radio buttons:

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

info = ["option 1",
        "option 2"
         ]

vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = tk.Label(main,text=i)
    btnYes = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=0,row=idx)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)


main.mainloop()
```

Next, I am trying to send selected radiobuttons data to a .txt file. Here is what I have tried:

```
def send(tk):
    text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    text_file.write(var1.get())
    text_file.close()


open = tk.Button(main, text="open", command = open).grid()

main.mainloop()
```

but this returns me an error code:

```
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: open() missing required argument 'file' (pos 1)
```

where im i going wrong?

Comment: try take out the `tk` from `def send(tk):`

Comment: Hi, this error shows up: `return self.func(*args)
TypeError: open() missing required argument 'file' (pos 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside your button widget, `command = open`.. you're basically calling the button that's why the error is showing up.

Change it to `command = send`, and also take out the 'tk' from function, as you don't need it.

Comment: wow.. do you know how to return every single var.get() onto a txt file?